# How do I take screenshots in 22.04 without copying to the clipboard?

Tags: 22.04, screenshot, clipboard

I just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 today, and, when I take a screenshot with PrtSc or Fn-Shift-S, it both saves the screenshot as a file *and* copies it to the clipboard, which is annoying when I have something already in the clipboard that I don't want to be clobbered by just taking a screenshot.

How do I restore the previous behavior, with the screenshot shortcut saving the screenshot to disk *without* clobbering the current contents of the clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the behavior of previous versions of Ubuntu.

1. Install "gnome-screenshot" it is is not installed.
2. In "Settings", "Keyboard", "Keyboard Shortcuts", section "Screenshots", disable the keyboard bindings to take a screenshot.
3. In the section "Custom Shortcuts", set up your own bindings to take a screenshot, providing the appropriate command. e.g. you could bind `gnome-screenshot -i` to PrtScr to have the dialog appear, `gnome-screenshot` to Shift+PrtScr for taking a screenshot of the entire screen, etc. Create variations of these commands to save screenshots to the clipboard instead of to a file.

See `man gnome-screenshot` for all command line options.

Comment: Working perfectly, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what desktop you are using, but one application that can do it is `xfce4-screenshooter`.

```
xfce4-screenshooter -f -d 10 -s /tmp/testshot.jpg
```

The above command will take a screenshot of the full screen with a 10 second delay and save the output to /tmp/testshot.jpg

There are more options that can be used.

```
$ xfce4-screenshooter --help
Usage:
  xfce4-screenshooter [OPTION…]

Help Options:
  -h, --help               Show help options
  --help-all               Show all help options
  --help-gtk               Show GTK+ Options

Application Options:
  -c, --clipboard          Copy the screenshot to the clipboard
  -d, --delay              Delay in seconds before taking the screenshot
  -f, --fullscreen         Take a screenshot of the entire screen
  -m, --mouse              Display the mouse on the screenshot
  --no-border              Removes the window border from the screenshot
  -o, --open               Application to open the screenshot
  -r, --region             Select a region to be captured by clicking a point of the screen without releasing the mouse button, dragging your mouse to the other corner of the region, and releasing the mouse button.
  -s, --save               File path or directory where the screenshot will be saved, accepts png, jpg and bmp extensions
  -i, --imgur              Host the screenshot on Imgur, a free online image hosting service
  -V, --version            Version information
  -w, --window             Take a screenshot of the active window
  --display=DISPLAY        X display to use
```